# Unable to configure `highWaterMark` on http.request in Node.js 20

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, tcp

I am using the below code to issue an HTTP request inside a Node.js 20 application. I want the node.js process to read more data from the socket in one go by allowing it to buffer more, thereby reducing the overall `.data` event count.

```js
http.request("https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/large.jpg?tr=orig", {
        highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 1024 // This value is making no impact on chunk size emitted by data event
    },
        (response) => {
            response
                .on('data', (chunk) => {
                    console.log(chunk.length) // This is never above 65536
                    body.push(chunk);
                    chunkCount++;
                }).on('end', () => {
                    const buffer = Buffer.concat(body)
                    var msg = `Size is ${buffer.length}, chunk count is ${chunkCount}. Avg chunk size is ${buffer.length / chunkCount}`;
                    console.log(msg)
                })
        }).end()
```

The resource at `https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/large.jpg?tr=orig` is 9.8MB image.
No matter what is the value of `highWaterMark`, `chunk.length` on `.data` event never exceeds `65536`.

What am I missing?